# "The Server method 'SetObject' Failed" on Exchange Server 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate, https, exchange-2010, bindings

I have Exchange Server 2010 with Windows Server 2008 64-bit.

Exchange Server and OAW is working fine.

However if I want to add another HTTPS port binding in IIS7, after adding the binding in IIS and IIS7 is reset, I open OWA in IIS8 and try to save any settings like signature etc.

I get:

```
The Server method 'SetObject' Failed
```

The error dialog box is as shown in the figure below.

After searching on the Internet I found that I need to buy another certificate for Exchange.

How can I remove this error without buying any additional certificates?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems at this point that Exchange is choking on the second HTTPS binding. It also seems you can only have one SSL port configured in IIS, and thus, only one SSL certificate. If you have multiple URLs that resolve to your mail server, and want to avoid certificate errors as a result of having the wrong CN on the certificate, you need to obtain an [Exchange Unified Communications Certificate](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929395) .

The reason I'd configured the second SSL binding in the first place was to avoid having to purchase a UC Certificate, as I wanted to use a basic class 1 certificate I already had for my external URL. In the end, I decided to use only the external URL and certificate, directing internal OWA users to the external URL. I then added an A record to our internal DNS servers to resolve requests for the external URL to the internal IP of the Exchange server.

Comment: Please consider to upvote if this question is helpful.